# ffmpeg - Overlay webm video (with alpha channel) over a static background image

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

I'm trying to overlay a webm video over an image. The video has opacity where the image should show through. All my attempts to do this via ffmpeg so far have shown the image in the first frame, then cut to the video only where the alpha part shows black (image behind is not visible).

The resolutions of the overlay and background image are both the same (1920x1080).

The closest command I've had was this however all transparency is lost and you just see the background image:

```bash
ffmpeg -y \
  -i transparent_overlay_video.webm \
  -i background_image.png \
  -filter_complex "[0:v]format=argb,geq=r='r(X,Y)':a='1.0*alpha(X,Y)'[zork]; \
  [1:v][zork]overlay" \
  -vcodec libx264 outputvideo.mp4
```

### Solution

```bash
ffmpeg -y \
  -c:v libvpx \
  -i transparent_overlay_video.webm \
  -i background_image.png \
  -filter_complex "[0:v]format=argb,geq=r='r(X,Y)':a='1.0*alpha(X,Y)'[zork]; \
  [1:v][zork]overlay" \
  -vcodec libx264 outputvideo.mp4
```

Thanks to Баяр-Гончикжапов below for the solution

Comment: Add `-c:v libvpx-vp9` or `-c:v libvpx` before `-i tr...webm`. Internal decoder doesn't support transparency

Answer (score 3):

```
ffmpeg -y \
  -c:v libvpx \
  -i transparent_overlay_video.webm \
  -i background_image.png \
  -filter_complex "[0:v]format=argb,geq=r='r(X,Y)':a='1.0*alpha(X,Y)'[zork]; \
  [1:v][zork]overlay" \
  -vcodec libx264 outputvideo.mp4
```

Comment: Maybe `-loop -i background_image.png` would have worked to keep the background for all video frames (not just appearing on first frame only)